# CMake not finding files - Can't build detectron with pytorch

Tags: cmake, pytorch

make ops for [detectron](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron) isn't working

```
export Caffe2_DIR=<path to my pytorch>/torch
make ops
```

#### Error Message

```
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops.dir/detectron/ops/zero_even_op.cc.o
In file included from /home/ubtuntu/detectron/detectron/ops/zero_even_op.cc:17:0:
/home/ubtuntu/detectron/detectron/ops/zero_even_op.h:20:33: fatal error: caffe2/core/context.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops.dir/detectron/ops/zero_even_op.cc.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops.dir/detectron/ops/zero_even_op.cc.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubtuntu/detectron/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/ubtuntu/detectron/detectron/ops/zero_even_op.cu:17:37: fatal error: caffe2/core/context_gpu.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMake Error at caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu_generated_zero_even_op.cu.o.cmake:219 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/ubtuntu/detectron/build/CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu.dir/detectron/ops/./caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu_generated_zero_even_op.cu.o


CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu.dir/detectron/ops/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu_generated_zero_even_op.cu.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu.dir/detectron/ops/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu_generated_zero_even_op.cu.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubtuntu/detectron/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:109: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe2_detectron_custom_ops_gpu.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubtuntu/detectron/build'
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubtuntu/detectron/build'
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'ops' failed
make: *** [ops] Error 2
```

#### What I've Tried

In the error message, it says it can't find `caffe2/core/context.h` however the file exists in `pytorch/caffe2/core/context.h`. So I've tried exporting the caffe2 folder instead of the torch folder, but then the build fails earlier
- I've also tried setting it to pytorch/cmake and pytorch/build folders

I then tried creating a caffe2 link to pytorch/caffe2 inside of pytorch/torch, however that had no effect. I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: Have you **installed** Caffer2 library? The path `pytorch/caffe2/core/context.h` is inside *source* tree.

Comment: I've built pytorch and run the verification tests recommended. That should have installed caffe2 (and I think the verification tests that). I can also see the file `pytorch/caffe2/core/context.h` but for some reason detectron can't find it

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood - I think `context.h` is only in the source, but I've also built and installed that source. I'm fairly unexperienced with building these projects.